How can I solve this error in wifislax 4.9

I can't understand why the commands not work please help me

wifislax is not based on Debian, it's based on Slackware https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=wifislax ... You can't execute the apt command on it, you need to find the package manager that it uses instead.

Slackware has no package manager unless you install one.  See the slackware documentation on package managers

You are trying to use apt, the Debian package manager, to update your machine. But Wifislax is based on Slackware, not Debian. So you have to use Slackware's package management tools instead:

pkgtools contains a set of applications that are to be used for basic package management.
slackpkg is a package manager and update tool for you to use with the official Slackware servers.

The command you are looking for is installpkg.
